# Is my function correct from the given instructions?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have created entry2_player helper function but I am looking for somebody that can verify if this is the correct responds to my given instructions below:

> This expects a string entry, consisting of a name, space, and an int score.
> When entry is "Sam 67", this function:
>
> displays 'malloc() for "Sam 67" ...'
> attempts malloc() for a Player:
> if malloc() fails, the function displays: 'Failed! Returning NULL'
> attempts to convert entry with *n = sscanf(...) to name and score of a
> Player variable. If successful, (indicated by *n = 2) displays 'at address: 0x000....' and returns its address.
> if entry is not valid, e.g. "Sam45", this function free the allocated memory,
> and displays 'Invalid entry string! Returning NULL', and returns NULL.
>
> REF: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Room for a short name string in Player:
#define NAME_SIZE   10
// Incremental number of memory, in units of pointers, by which to increase
// size of Player pointer array:
#define MALLOC_INCR  5

typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_SIZE] ;
    int  score ;
} Player ;


Player * entry2_Player(char *entry, int *n) {
   char name[10];
   int score;


   printf("\nmalloc() for %s ...", entry);

   Player *pID = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(entry));
   if (pID == NULL){
   printf("Failed! Returning NULL");
   return NULL;
   }

   *n = sscanf(entry, "%s %d", name, &score);
   if (*n !=2){
      printf("Invalid entry string!");
      free(pID);
      return NULL;
   }
   else{
      printf("at address: 0x%p", &n);
      return pID;
      }
   }
```

In my main function I am required to:

> Create a single Player variable, using entry2_Player() with the string "Robin 78" and
> display it with show_Player(). Store the Player in the array from part 2. Add a fifth Player
> to the array directly from entry2_Player(). Display the Player array with show_Players()

I am looking to see if my return variables in entry2_player are correct in order for me to continue with this next instructions.

Comment: Right off the top, it is very bad form to define a function (write its code) in a header file. The content of a `.h` is to _share_ function declarations (prototypes) and _tokens_ such as MAX_INT or EXIT_FAILURE. By "share" I mean that header files can/will be included in multiple "compilation units" (ie: `.c` files). Code (defining functions) belongs in `.c` files; not in a `.h` file. (There are exceptions, naturally, but this question is not in that category.)

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're actually doing:

You allocate a block of memory of size of pointer to char. On current systems, this could be 8 bytes. Then you're trying to read two items from the input string `entry` into the (locally - stack - allocated) variables `name` and `score`. If that succeeds, you're returning the 'untouched' allocated block of memory.

What you probably want to do:

Allocate a block of memory of size `Player`. Without knowing the system specs, `sizeof(Player) > sizeof(char*)`. Then you want to read two items from the input string `entry` into the fields `name` and `score` of the allocated `Player` object. And if that succeeds, you'll return the 'properly initialized' `Player` object.

Btw.

```
printf("at address: 0x%p", &n);
```

What do you want to present here? `n` is a pointer, that means it contains the address of an `int`. The above statement prints the address of the pointer.

I think, the following was the intention:

```
printf("at address: %p", pID); //%p prints the address in hex format, preceded by '0x'
```

---

`sizeof entry == sizeof(char*)` will not return the length of the string `entry`, but the number of bytes required to store a pointer to char.

`strlen(entry)` will give you the length of the string `entry`.

---

Based on the comment below, here the formal explanation:

```
Player * entry2_Player(char *entry, int *n) 
{
    printf("\nmalloc() for %s ...", entry);

    //alloc Player object
    Player *pID = malloc(sizeof(Player));
    if (pID == NULL){
        printf("Failed! Returning NULL");
        return NULL;
    }

    //parse entry into the fields of pID
    *n = sscanf(entry, "%s %d", pID->name, &pID->score);
    if (*n !=2){
        printf("Invalid entry string!");
        free(pID);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        printf("at address: %p", pID); //address of allocated memory
        return pID;
    }
}
```

Comment: so it would be:

Player *pID = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(Player) > sizeof(char*)); 
Player *pID = (Player *)malloc(sizeof(*n));

and what is the purpose of the last section of size of entry == sizeof(char*)?

Comment: What are you doing? `Player pID = malloc(sizeof(Player));`. That is it.With the rest, i wanted to convince you, that a `Player` object needs more memory, than to hold a pointer to char. Also, if the function is returning a `Player` object, so why an allocation other than `Player`? Does that make sense?